# Odoo 10 report table foreach line

Tags: python, xml, foreach, html-table, odoo-10

Here is python code:

```
@api.depends('employee_id')
    def create_employee_report(self):
        count = 0
        employee_data = {}
        for employee in self.env['hr.employee'].search([]):
            if employee.socialsecurityno:
                count = count + 1
                employee_data ={'sira':str(count),'sigortano':str(employee.socialsecurityno)}
        return employee_data
```

and view.xml

```
    <tbody>
    <tr t-foreach="o.create_employee_report()" t-as="t">
      <td class="td-lrbotborder">
        <span t-field="t.sira" style=" font-size:13px;" />
      </td>
    <tr>
```

and here is error message:

```
Error to render compiling AST
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_fields'
Template: hr_module.sosyal_sigorta_report_document
Path: /templates/t/t/div/div/div/div[11]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/span
Node: <span t-field="t.sira" style=" font-size:13px;"/>
```

How will I use t-foreach? I am trying create table columns and lines. This part will fill lines but I could not make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my xml;

```
<table class="table table-condensed" style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="td-allborder" style="width:30px; font-size:11px;">Sıra</th>
                <th class="td-topbotborder" style="width:75px; font-size:10px;">Sigortalı No.</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr t-foreach="o.create_employee_report()" t-as="t">
                <td class="td-lrbotborder">
                    <span t-esc="t_value" style=" font-size:13px;" />
                </td>
                <td class="td-botborder">
                    <span t-esc="t_value" style=" font-size:13px;" />
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

and here is python file;

```
@api.depends('employee_id')
    def create_employee_report(self):
        count = 0
        employee_list = []
        employee_data = {}
        for employee in self.env['hr.employee'].search([]):
            if employee.socialsecurityno:
                employee_data ={'sira':str(count),
                                'sigortano':str(employee.socialsecurityno),
                                'kimlikno':str(employee.personelno),
                                'isim':employee.name}
                count = count + 1
                employee_list.append(employee_data)
        print employee_list
        return employee_list
```

Edit: I solved the problem like;

```
<span t-esc="t['sira']" style=" font-size:13px;" />
```

Thanks for your replying.

Comment: Please, where this piece of python code should be. in models folder or report?

Answer (score 2):

Change **t-field** by **t-esc** and **t.sira** by **t_value** exemple :

```
 <tr t-foreach="o.create_employee_report()" t-as="t">
  <td class="td-lrbotborder">
      <span t-esc="t_value" style=" font-size:13px;" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but how will i get array items employee_data ={'sira':str(count),'sigortano':str(employee.socialsecurityno)} for example i want "sira" and "sigortano"

Comment: hi , **t** is the  key of your dict and **t_value** is the value. exempe: {'sira':1,'sigortano':'test'}  t = 1 and t_value= test

Comment: but still i can not do what i want, it show all dict on 1 column. i can not make 'sira' to 'SIRA' column , 'sigortano' to 'SIGORTA' column. This show  {'sira':1,'sigortano':'test'} in 'SIRA' column.

Comment: You can show me your code **XML**  if you can.                                   I have a bug in my last comment example: {'sira':1,'sigortano':'test'}  **t** is equal a **sira** and **t_value** eq **1**